# Send a broadcast message from Unity app on Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, message, communication, broadcast

I need to send a broadcast message from a Unity3D application running on Android device. I've already seen this tutorial

http://jeanmeyblum.weebly.com/scripts--tutorials/communication-between-an-android-app-and-unity

but I need exactly the opposite thing. The unity app is the sender and another android app is the receiver. Is this hard to obtain?

This is my code:

1) This is the code from which I created a .jar to import in unity

```
package com.example.unitysender;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction("UnityToAndroid");
        sendBroadcast(intent);
        finish();
    }

}
```

2) This is the code in Unity, the method CreateInstance is public static so I can call it from a button.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MainActivity : MonoBehaviour {

    static AndroidJavaClass jc;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    public static void CreateInstance()
    {
        jc = new AndroidJavaClass("com.example.unitysender.MainActivity");
        jc.CallStatic("createInstance");
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure it's all wrong so if you can guide me in the right direction I'll be happy. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is possible. Where is your code?

Comment: did you get this resolved?

Comment: I started from this, with little changes

https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/06/creating-an-android-java-plugin-for-unity3d/